# Can not to properly define url path for main page

Tags: django

I have project with multiple apps.

```
#my project directory
forecast 
    #app
    authorization 
          views.py
    #project directory where settings
    forecast
          settings.py
          urls.py
    #here html templates located
    templates
          main
              base.html
```

Inside `forecast/urls.py` i defined the following

```
from django.contrib import admin                             
from django.urls import path,include,re_path               
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views                                                                     
from authorization.views import
index_page_view

urlpatterns=[
path(r'^$',index_page_view,name='home')]
```

In `authorization/views.py` defined view to render main page

```
def index_page_view(request):                                  
       return render(request,'main/base.html',{})
```

When i am open http://127.0.0.1:8000 i see the 404 error with following message

```
 ^$ [name='home']
The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

What is wrong inmy setup ?

Comment: First parameter of `path` should be a string, not a regular expression. `path('', index_page_view, name='home')`

Answer (score 0):

I always find that, the best way to handle routing in django is like this.

```
from django.contrib import admin                             
from django.urls import path, include               
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views   

urlpatterns=[
path('', include(authorization.urls))
]
```

Then in authorization.urls

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import

urlpatterns=[
path('', index_page_view, name='home'))
]
```

I know just specifying the path on the main url works too, but I just prefer doing it this way like in the documentation.